# Can i route a call to another number in twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I want to start using twilio in my company and i wanted to ask if was it possible to code something in python or php that forwards a call from my customer to my manager and all calls from my tax consultant to me?

And if it was possible could you please put a template into your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use no code/low code using Twilio Studio to easily set this up.

**Options:**

1. You can either have two separate Twilio numbers that handle the routing
2. Or prompt the caller in the IVR who they would like to speak to and route
3. Or based on CallerID, determine where the call should be routed, all are viable options.

The [Connect Call To](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/connect-call) Widget handles the rest!

[Speed up your development process with Twilio Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14FXnUgrZ6w&t=48s)

[Press 1 For Sales: Building an IVR for Your Startup
(Watch Replay)](https://www.crowdcast.io/e/press-1-for-sales) 
*(starts at timecode 12:50).